# PhoneApplicationPage subclass not working

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

At the start of .xaml file for a page I have:

```
<framework:PhoneApplicationPageBase
```

and in the.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class MyPage : PhoneApplicationPageBase
```

In App.xaml I have:

```
<Application
    ...
    xmlns:framework="clr-namespace:..."
```

but I get the error "'framework' is an undeclared prefix" when compiling the xaml file.  The PhoneApplicationPageBase class is working fine in another .xaml page file (I wrote it a while ago).

Is there something I've forgotten that I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the namespace prefix in the pages xaml file. Resources can be referenced from the App.xaml file but the imported namespaces are not propagated to the other pages in your project.

If you add *xmlns:framework="clr-namespace:..."* to the root element of the page it should be fine.

Comment: The PhoneApplicationPageBase IS the root element of the page, so I'm not sure how to add the namespace declaration before this.

Comment: You don't need to add it before, as long as the namespace declaration is in the root element it's OK: <framework:PhoneApplicationPageBase xmlns:framework="clr-namespace:...">